# javascript example in google site is having issue

Tags: google-drive-api

After changing the CLIENT_ID to the ID in my google api access, I tried to test the javascript example in a page using HTML Box in my google site; when I tried to save the HTML Box, get failed to load external url client.js?onload=handleClientLoad message. How to make the javascript example work using google site?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var CLIENT_ID = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
   var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

   /**
    * Called when the client library is loaded to start the auth flow.
    */
   function handleClientLoad() {
     window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
   }

   /**
    * Check if the current user has authorized the application.
    */
   function checkAuth() {
     alert('checkAuth()');
     gapi.auth.authorize(
         {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true},
         handleAuthResult);
   }

   /**
    * Called when authorization server replies.
    *
    * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
    */
   function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
     alert('handleAuthResult()');
     if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
       // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to the API.
       var filePicker = document.getElementById('filePicker');
       filePicker.style.visibility = '';
       filePicker.onchange = uploadFile;
     } else {
       // No access token could be retrieved, force the authorization flow.
       gapi.auth.authorize(
           {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': false},
           handleAuthResult);
     }
   }

   /**
    * Start the file upload.
    *
    * @param {Object} evt Arguments from the file selector.
    */
   function uploadFile(evt) {
     gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
       var file = evt.target.files[0];
       insertFile(file);
     });
   }

   /**
    * Insert new file.
    *
    * @param {File} fileData File object to read data from.
    * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
    */
   function insertFile(fileData, callback) {
     const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
     const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
     const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
     reader.onload = function(e) {
       var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
       var metadata = {
         'title': fileData.name,
         'mimeType': contentType
       };

       var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
       var multipartRequestBody =
           delimiter +
           'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
           JSON.stringify(metadata) +
           delimiter +
           'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
           'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
           '\r\n' +
           base64Data +
           close_delim;

       var request = gapi.client.request({
           'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
           'method': 'POST',
           'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
           'headers': {
             'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
           },
           'body': multipartRequestBody});
       if (!callback) {
         callback = function(file) {
           console.log(file)
         };
       }
       request.execute(callback);
     }
   }
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
<div>
 <!--Add a file picker for the user to start the upload process -->
 <input type="file" id="filePicker" style="visibility: hidden" />
</div>
```